# Base Elements plugin works locally, not on server

Tags: email, plugins, filemaker

I have installed BE_version 4.1.4 plugin on FileMaker Server 19. I can see the plugin in the extensions folder. I have the same version installed on my local client. I am running a script to send an html email with an attachment. When I run it locally it goes just fine. When I run the script on the server, making sure the same records are showing when the pdf is created, I get an error in the script step that sets the curl options. The calculation is this: BE_CurlSetOption ( "CURLOPT_USE_SSL";  "CURLUSESSL_ALL" ). It returns an error of 2: CURLE_FAILED_INIT (2)
Very early initialization code failed. This is likely to be an internal error or problem, or a resource problem where something fundamental couldn't get done at init time.

Why does the script work in my local file but not when run on the server? Same script, same BE version, FM19 all the way.  The server is hosted on a Mac, I am running locally on a PC.

Comment: Have you enabled plugins in the FileMaker Server admin console?

Comment: Yes, everything was set up correctly, it was a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a great deal of searching I found the solution. When FileMaker gets a file path it comes complete with a "/" at the beginning. I removed that first character and BE was able to handle the task on my Windows machine. On Mac, BE requires "Volumes" to be added before the first "/". Having done that, my mail request was honored just fine. Mail was sent to the spam box, so watch for that!

Answer (score 0):

Here some info about filemaker paths.

https://docs.baseelementsplugin.com/article/514-notes-about-file-paths